# Customize tablehead of react-gridjs

Tags: reactjs, gridjs

Intead of using the default search bar, I'd like to customize it as follows:

1. Add a button in front of the search bar.
2. Use an icon (`<i className="fa fa-search"/>`) in the search placeholder.

[image]

Here's my code so far:

```
import { Grid, _ } from 'gridjs-react';

const tableColumns = [
  'Name',
  'Phone',
  {
    name: 'Custom component',
    formatter: (text) => _(<b>{text}</b>)
  }
]
const tableData = [
  ['John', 12345, 'myText1'],
  ['Mike', 67891, 'myText2'],
]

export default function myCustomGrid() {
  return (
    <Grid
      sort={true}
      search={true} // This adds the search inp
      columns={tableColumns}
      data={tableData}
      language={{
        search: {
          placeholder: ' Search...'
        }
      }}
      pagination={{
        enabled: true,
        limit: 2
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a good use-case for a [portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html).

This allows us to more flexibly decide where we render our button. Using portals we can make the button a sibbling of the search input:

```
const gridjsHeadRoot = document.getElementsByClassName("gridjs-head");

class GridHeaderButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.el = document.createElement("button");
    this.el.innerText = "Click";
    this.el.style.cssText = `
      background-color: #0069d9;
      color: #fff; 
      border-radius: .25rem;
      padding: .375rem .75rem;
      float: right
    `;
    this.el.onclick = function () {
      // Do something
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    gridjsHeadRoot[0].appendChild(this.el);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    gridjsHeadRoot[0].removeChild(this.el);
  }

  render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, this.el);
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
function MyCustomGrid() {
  return (
    <Grid
      sort={true}
      search={true} // This adds the search inp
      columns={tableColumns}
      data={tableData}
      language={{
        search: {
          placeholder: " Search...",
        },
      }}
      pagination={{
        enabled: true,
        limit: 2,
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyCustomGrid />
      <GridHeaderButton />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The order of where you put `GridHeaderButton` is important here. Because `GridHeaderButton` targets an element rendered inside `MyCustomGrid` which means you should put `GridHeaderButton` below `CustomGrid` or it will not work.

---

[Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-edison-2i2cs?file=/src/App.js:1179-1657)

Comment: Nice trick! However, there are 2 minors issues in the example: 1-Column hover is triggered when the button is hovered. 2-The column text is slightly above the sort arrow.

Comment: @AnisBenna I've updated by answer with, I think, a better approach. It should solve the issues you mentioned.